# Difficulty with loading modules and Haskell GHCi

Tags: haskell

I've got a text file with the following code:

```
fib 0 = 1

fib 1 = 1 

fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

evenOdd n = if (mod n 2) == 0 then 1 else 0

sumFib 0 = 0

sumFib 1 = 0

sumFib n = (evenOdd (fib n))*(fib n) + sumFib (n-1)
```

Basically, I'm trying to define three functions, where the third relies on the first two. However, when I load this in GHCi, while fib works fine, evenOdd gives me the following error:

> interactive>:1:1:1 error:  Variable not in scope: evenOdd :: Integer
>   -> t

This confuses me, because if I type that exact line of code into *Main>, evenOdd works fine. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure you are importing correctly / have saved your file before importing? Both functions work fine here. `*Main> evenOdd 202` gives 
`1` and `*Main> fib 21` gives 
`17711`

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://ideone.com/mbH1pC), voting to close.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error, when I use :l and the filename (and GHCi says that the file loaded correctly).

Comment: You could try and `:edit filename.hs` to check if you are actually loading the right file. Maybe you are in the wrong directory / loading up an old version / didn't save properly.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `evenOdd n = mod n 2`, or ```evenOdd = (`mod` 2)``` if you're zealous about point-free. The `if`/`then`/`else` is unneeded extra work. Of course, the wasted/duplicated work in `fib` and `sumFib` is going to dwarf that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my ghci everything seems to work fine. As you can use fib I'm sure you loaded the file correctly but it seems like you didn't save after adding `evenOdd` to the file before actually loading.

Try:

- Save file first
- `:l filename.hs`
- `evenOdd 10`

This worked on my device. If for some reason this is still not working, you could try and run a `:edit filename.hs` to see what file you are actually loading in. Maybe this file is a different one / different version than you expected it to be.

My terminal output:

```
➜  Desktop ls
PO.pptx     untitled.hs
➜  Desktop ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l untitled.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( untitled.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 1 module loaded.
*Main> fib 20
10946
*Main> evenOdd 2023
0
*Main> evenOdd 2
1
*Main>
```

Comment: Thanks! It ended up being a saving problem.